# What does "brood" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

If the young have already hatched, there's nothing to brood, is there? In no dictionary did I see that "brood" can mean "care for the young" as well, only "sit on eggs to hatch them"

> Once the young hatch, the female **broods** for 8-10 days and the male bring food to both the female and the young.

*(from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hatch))*

Comment: In some species, the young birds can run about as soon as they are hatched, but in other species they are helpless in the nest for some time and have to be kept warm by the parent bird sitting on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiktionary:

> 2. (*transitive*) To protect (something that is gradually maturing); to foster.
>
> > *Under the rock was a midshipman fish, **brooding** a mass of eggs.*

OED:

> 2.a: To cherish (young brood) under the wings, as a hen does; often figurative. 
> 5. To sit as a hen on eggs; to sit or hover with outspread cherishing wings.